# how to use "cellmousedown" event in sfdatagrid syncfustion

Tags: vb.net, syncfusion

hi I'm using Syncfusion I wanted to apply the following code in my project but sfdatagrid doesn't have "cellmousedown" event!

```
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then

        If e.ColumnIndex <> -1 And e.RowIndex <> -1 Then

            Me.DataGridView1.ClearSelection()

            Dim cell = Me.DataGridView1.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)

            Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell

            cell.Selected = True 'Needed if you right click twice on the same cell

            DataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = mnuCell

        End If

    End If
```

how to apply it.

Comment: I think the first question should be exactly what are you trying to do.  SfDataGrid has a whole lot of built in functionality around context menus already. https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/datagrid/interactivefeatures

Comment: @Hursey yes but when I click the right button it doesn't give the real values for the row , so I need to send left click event before opening the ContextMenuStrip